# Backend automatically removes leading zeros / 0 from zip codes - Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, customer-address, magento2.3.4, zipcode

In Germany, several cities have a leading 0 in the zip code e.g. 07907. When customers with such a zip place an order, magento removes the first zero and stores a 4-digit zip code with that customer and transaction even though the customer's input is a 5-digit requirement.

[image]

Even if i try to edit the shipping address afterwards, it still won't save the first 0.

[image]

This causes massive validation errors with DHL or other fulfillment partners.
I can't beliebe that a shop software would not have thought about zips like this, this can't be a default setting?

Edit: I found a strange workaround. If I edit the address and add a 1 to it, making it 17907 and save, it changes the zip to 17907. If I then change 17907 to 07907 and save, it actually shows the right zip 07907... does that mean it is a storing issue ?

Comment: I just checked and I don’t see this in my German M2 store, plz   with leading zero is saved correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I will look further into the issue to see what could be the reason behind this.

Comment: Same problem here with Magento 2.4.4. Any news about a solution here?

Comment: I had a self-written module that capped the transaction number after four digits. It turned out that this also was the reason behind the cut-off zip numbers